# Как отправить данные построчно из dataGrid в базу данных?

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf

Приложение WPF. В наличии вот такой метод:

```
static public void SQLUpdate()
{
     try
     {
          command = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE guests SET id = @id, fio = @FIO " +  "WHERE id= @id", connection);
          command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id",?????);
          adapter.UpdateCommand = command;          
          adapter.Update(DS, "guests"); //
     }
}
```

также имеется `dataGrid`. Как мне обновить (и послать изменения в БД) целой строки этого `dataGrid` поколоночно?

По логике, надо добавить вместо **"?????"** что-то типа `Columns[0]`, `Columns[1]` и тд..(содержащее данные из первого, второго,N-го столбца `dataGrid`).

Answer (score 0):

У вас по идее должен быть класс свойствам которого бы соответствовали столбцы в таблице БД и в dataGrid, а List<ВашКласс> подключен к dataGrid.ItemsSource, плюс
нужен экземпляр ВашКласс для текущей выбранной строки в dataGrid, который подключен к dataGrid.SelectedItem . Ну и собственно пробегаете по свойствам текущего выбранного экземпляра и подсовываете их вместо ваших ?????